# iPhone display zoom install application by Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, resolution

I use iPhone6. I set display zoom mode "standard". 
I installed and tested my app resolution (375 x 667).
Today, I changed iphone display zoom mode "zoom" and chagned again mode "stardard". Then, I installed my app to my iPhone by Xcode.
Resolution is 320 x 568. And never back to stardard resoultion (375 x 667)
I have no idea. What is the problem. 
I guess, Xcode bug.. 
Please Help..!

Comment: did you try manually deleting the app on the phone, and cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: Thanks ApolloSoftware to reply. I deleted app long pressed. how can I do perfectly delete app on the phone?

Comment: I found out the reason why display only zoom. because I use LuachImage(Assets.xcassets). That is the reason. but I'm still finding how to fix it